# Firebase JS Error: getToken aborted due to token change

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a Firebase error "**Error: getToken aborted due to token change**" while running Firestore transaction using the JavaScript library. The error doesn't get thrown every time and I couldn't find the pattern. I suppose I've implemented some race conditions somewhere.

The user flow in my app goes like this:

1. Register a new account & submit an additional string in the same form
2. Log user in after registration using the same credentials
3. After log in, take that additional string and save it to Firestore (in a transaction).
4. Transaction fails due to `Error: getToken aborted due to token change.`

**The flow of promises:**

```
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(signupError => {
        // no problems here
      })
      .then(() => {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      })
      .catch(loginError => {
        // no problem here
      })
      .then((user) => {
        // Database write call which fails (see lower code block)
        return this.claimInput.writeClaimedPlace(user.user.uid, claimedPlace);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // "getToken aborted" ERROR GETS CAUGHT HERE, transaction fails    
      })    
    }
```

The database transaction call

```
firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {

  return transaction.get(usersBusinessRef).then(function(usersBusinesDoc) {

    let claimedPlaces = [];
    if (usersBusinesDoc.exists && usersBusinesDoc.data().claimedPlaces) {
      claimedPlaces = usersBusinesDoc.data().claimedPlaces;
    }
    claimedPlaces.push(claimedPlace);

    return transaction.set(usersBusinessRef, { claimedPlaces }, { merge: true });
  });
});
```

I couldn't find the error anywhere on google.

I'm thinking the error is caused by the token change that happens at log in. On the other hand I'm reading that Firebase accepts old tokens for a few more moments. Any thoughts?

Comment: It occurs to me too (android). I have checked my current user which was already logged in, but when I ran the transaction, it failed due to the similar error. Current workaround is to manually get the data and then update.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error[error code] while debugging my client which was connecting to firebase via a React App.

The solution was

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Putting the above inside the rules part of the firestore settings which apparently means you need to allow reads for external apis but writes are blocked and it was previously blocking both reads and writes.

This could be one of the issues if you are trying to read from your client/server

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

- **DISCLAIMER:** * **I am not an Expert at firebase. I am not sure if this would compromise your DB to be written by external apis since you are opening your firestore firewall by doing this**

P.S. there is a `firebase-admin` module which I think helps in doing writes by handling authentication in a separate fashion. I think that module is more suited for writes and the normal `firebase.firestore(app)` is for reads.